# simultaneous drag two objects with multitouch in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag, multi-touch

I am trying to drag two objects simultaneously with multitouch in AS3. My goal is to have the user pinch the two objects together. Right now I cannot get both to be moving at the same time. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

//

```
bullseye4a.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, fl_ClickToDrag4a);

function fl_ClickToDrag4a(event: TouchEvent): void {
bullseye4a.startDrag();
}

bullseye4b.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, fl_ClickToDrag4b);
function fl_ClickToDrag4b(event: TouchEvent): void {
bullseye4b.startDrag();
}

bullseye4a.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, fl_ReleaseToDrop4a);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop4a(event: TouchEvent): void {
bullseye4a.stopDrag();

}
bullseye4b.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, fl_ReleaseToDrop4b);
function fl_ReleaseToDrop4b(event: TouchEvent): void {
bullseye4b.stopDrag();
}
addChild(bullseye4a);
addChild(bullseye4b);
```

Comment: What does it do right now? Try not to use startDrag() in that case but update the x/y based on the finger's position on some enterframe, interval or touchmove.

Comment: right now i can only control one at a time. when i put the second finger down, it is perceived as a new controller for the first object - basically i cam moving the first object although my finger is not on top of it anymore

Comment: That's what I was assuming. Probably the way starDrag() works (I guess it was never designed with multitouch in mind). You should try what I mentioned above.

Comment: how would I be able to make each object know which finger to follow?  i'm new to multitouch

Comment: As far as I remember there is a touchPointID (or something like that) on the TouchEvent object. You associate that id with your object(s) on touch begin. Then, on touch move, you check from that event what is the touchPointID. If the same id is associated with an object, you move it. I guess it should work. EDIT: Check this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#touchPointID Another edit: Oh btw, do not forget to put your move listener to the stage, not to the object!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easiest and most direct way to do what you're asking:

```
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

    var curTouchPoints:Dictionary = new Dictionary(); //a dictionary to store which objects are related to which touch points


    bullseye4a.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchStart); //add both objects touch begin listener
    bullseye4b.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchStart);

    //add a global touch move listener
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, touchMove);




    function touchStart(e:TouchEvent):void {
        //create an object that stores the offset and a the object touched, then add it to the dictionary
        curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID] = {obj: e.currentTarget, offsetX: e.localX, offsetY: e.localY}; //store the current object in the dictionary

        //listen for the touch end event 
        e.currentTarget.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,touchEnd);
    }

    function touchMove(e:TouchEvent):void {
        //move this object to the current touch position
        //find the object by looking up the touchPointId in the dictionary (since e.currentTarget will be the stage, and e.target could be the child of what you really want OR the stage if touch 'leaves' the object)
        DisplayObject(curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID].obj).x = e.stageX - curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID].offsetX;  //subtract the offset so the object doesn't snap to the registration point on the first touch move
        DisplayObject(curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID].obj).y = e.stageY - curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID].offsetY;
    }

    function touchEnd(e:TouchEvent):void {
        //remove the dictionary item now that the touch has ended
        delete curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID];

        //remove the touch end listener
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,touchEnd);
    }
```

Comment: Local coordinates? I'd say parent-transformed, otherwise if `e.target==e.currentTarget` then the target will move weirdly. Please test and fix.

Comment: I seriously doubt this would work as you have the TOUCH_MOVE assigned to the display object itself, should be on stage. It happens a lot that you "leave" the touched object.

Comment: @Fygo - it works.  Not sure what you mean by "leave" the touched object? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @LDMS, Sure, sorry: Try to pull your finger real fast or have slower device - the object will stay behind and your finger "won't be touch_move-ing it", but the display object beneath it. That's why touch move should go on stage rather than on the object itself. Not to even mention if you have display objects over the dragged object. You can actually reproduce it even with mouse_move and a display object, without a touch device. It will lead to a rather jerky movement. (last time I did this was 2 years ago but I doubt anything changed since)

Comment: @Fygo - Ah ok, yes I see what you're referring to now (I have encountered that with mouse events naturally and do always use the stage to listen for MOVE/UP events), the problem with touch is that there isn't a global list of current touch points and their corresponding x/y coordinates so you'd have to track all that manually. I'll update the answer again. Thanks for contributing

Comment: @LDMS that looks much better indeed and is something I was referring to in my comment (under the question). No, thanks to you, your feedback/help is always appreciated!

Comment: can someone help explain approaches to calculating the offset (so it doesnt jerk to the registration point)? i've trying to get an offset in touchMove() that's the registrationPoint - touchPoint (stage x pos) but cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: wow. i got it working, but the code was nowhere near as elegant as yours! my mistake was trying to capture offset in touchMove, it should be in touchStart like u said. super thanks for the update.

Comment: Mind the question, but while the code works flawlessly, I can't figure out the way to filter out the events that were "NOT" started by the object (touchStart), since the code as-is throws error if stage is pressed (due to stage listening to touchMove event, and therefore not findinf the object in Dictionary).
I'm a total beginner in Air/AS3, so sorry if this is some basics that I'm unable to figure out. :)

Comment: Got it!!!
Just needed to add "" if (curTouchPoints[e.touchPointID]) {  DisplayObject...."  inside the touchMove function! :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Glad you got that figured out @ThatMarc .

Comment: Final question though, if I may :) Let's say I have 10 sprites  on stage (frames), each of them containing another sprite (knobs), and I want the knobs* to be elements I can drag -> I add event listener touchStart to the knob child, got it. I also need to add parent's x and y offset in calculation to get it right -> Got it.  Mistery though: How would I limit the knobs to be able to only move inside it's parents (=frames), BUT keep the touchMove event active (= not trigger touchEnd even if leaving both, knob and frame with the finger)? I'm sure its simple thing for a pro like you :P BIG thanks!

Comment: @ThatMarc - depends on how you move the knobs. If you're using `startDrag` you can pass in a rectangle as the dragable bounds.  If you're using an enter frame handler or the like, then you can check the bounds manually.   I'd recommend asking your own question about it showing your current code as it's more appropriate place to figure it out than in comments on a different answer/question.   I don't recall if startDrag works with multiple objects simultaneous though

Comment: Thats what I thought about startDrag. Therefore, I rather implemented some math to check the boundaries manually. Even hittest would not be useful since I want the object to move "inside" the parent, so it returns always true. But all in all I got it figured good enough for the start, I think. Thanks a lot!! :)