# How do I detect double drag when one of them is stop dragging?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I have 2 movieclips. I wanted the player can control those 2 at the same time. And I want if the player stop dragging the one of them, the other one can still be control by the player while the other one is not. How can I do that?

Here's my code :

```
var _action1:Boolean = false;
var _action2:Booelan = false;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);

button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOut); // to detect if press is out of range

function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (e.target == button1) {
        _action1 = true;
    }
    if (e.target == button2) {
        _action2 = true;
    }

function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (e.target == button1) {
        _action1 = false;
    }
    if (e.target == stage) {
        _action1 = false;
    }
    if (e.target == button2) {
        _action2 = false;
    }

function mouseOut(e:MouseEvent): void {
    _action2 = false;
}
```

I have try that code, but doesn't work well, I cannot control both of them(`button1` and `button2`).

**+** I want my application to works on `android`. I have try it on my `android` and I can control the button using `MouseEvent` method. But I can only use single control on button. So if I want to control another button, I have to do `MOUSE_UP` then do `MOUSE_DOWN` on the button I want to control.

Comment: By the way, the `button1` and `button2` is a `MovieClip` not a `Button`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simultaneous drag two objects with multitouch in as3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136960/simultaneous-drag-two-objects-with-multitouch-in-as3)

Answer (score 1):

One approach that comes to mind would be to allow the user to indicate which movie clips to drag based on a key press. For instance, movie clip 1 would be dragged if the A key were pressed down and movie clip 2 would be dragged if Z key were pressed down. Then the user can hold down both keys to drag both movie clips and if the user releases one key, that respective MovieClip will stop dragging.

Comment: I'm trying to use it on `android` phone, so I used `MouseEvent` method, please help me.

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure MouseEvent doesn't apply to an android device as there is no mouse.  Use TouchEvent instead.

Comment: I have try this code on my own `android` phone, and it works, I can control the `MovieClip` but only one, if I want to control the other one, I have to do like `MOUSE_UP` then do like `MOUSE_DOWN` on the other one that I want to control.

Comment: Probably because it can't have two mouses. This has been discussed very well at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136960/simultaneous-drag-two-objects-with-multitouch-in-as3 and a very good solution has been posted there.